# Error sending formData with axios and redux saga

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, multipartform-data, redux-saga

I'm trying to send some multipart form data from a react-native app to the backend with the objective of update a profile photo.

My saga call is...

```
// react native code
export function* uploadFile({ payload }) {
  const { uri } = payload.data;

  try {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', uri);
    const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' };

    const response = yield call(api.post, '/upload', data, headers);
    yield put(fileUploadSuccess(response.data));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(fileUploadFailure());
  }
}
```

The code above hits the backend (below), but the file data comes in the body (req.body.file) of the request instead of the request itself (req.file).

In postman request, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

```
// backend code
ImgUpload.uploadToGcs = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.file) return next();

  // omitted code
```

Answer (score 0):

Postman auto detects the form-data and multipart boundary. In case of browser requests, we need to allow the browser to auto-detect the Content-Type and set the boundary.

Remove the hard-coded `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` from headers and replace that with `'contentType': false`. Following request should work as expected.

```
export function* uploadFile({ payload }) {
  const { uri } = payload.data;

  try {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', uri);
    const headers = { 'contentType': false }; // allow browser to detect content-type

    const response = yield call(api.post, '/upload', data, headers);
    yield put(fileUploadSuccess(response.data));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(fileUploadFailure());
  }
}
```